# Summing attribute in a array of hashes and grouping them

Tags: ruby

I have an array like this:

```
res = [
  {:partner_name=>"company 1", :partner_id=>787, :value=>1}, 
  {:partner_name=>"company 2", :partner_id=>768, :value=>1},
  {:partner_name=>"company 3", :partner_id=>769, :value=>1},
  {:partner_name=>"company 1", :partner_id=>787, :value=>2}
]
```

What I'm trying to do is to create an array that would hold the sum of all values per `partner_id`. For example the output of above would be :

```
[{:partner_name=>"company 1", :partner_id=>787, :value=>3}, 
 {:partner_name=>"company 2", :partner_id=>768, :value=>1},
 {:partner_name=>"company 3", :partner_id=>769, :value=>1}]
```

Tried to play around with it:

```
res.each do |r|
  if hash.key?(r[:partner_id])
    hash[:value] += r[:value]
  else
    hash = r
  end
end
```

With this and couple other tries, could not get it to work.

Comment: I trust you don't mine my small edit. By assigning a variable (`res`) to your array of hashes, readers can refer to that variable in comments and answers without having to define it. You should do that for all input objects in all examples given in SO questions.

Answer (score 2):

The following code works. Basically, two steps:

Group the hashes by their `partner_id`; join these groups with the `value` summed.

```
arr = [{ partner_name: "company 1", partner_id: 787, value: 1 }, 
       { partner_name: "company 2", partner_id: 768, value: 1},
       { partner_name: "company 3", partner_id: 769, value: 1},
       { partner_name: "company 1", partner_id: 787, value: 2}]

arr.group_by { |hash| hash[:partner_id] }.map do |_k, values| 
  { partner_name: values.first[:partner_name], 
    partner_id: values.first[:partner_id], 
    value: values.sum { |val| val[:value] } }
end
```

Or there's the following, which doesn't read as nicely but makes use of `merge`'s block arg:

```
arr.group_by { |hash| hash[:partner_id] }.map do |_k, values| 
  values.reduce({}) do |a, e| 
    a.merge(e) do |key, old_val, new_val| 
      key == :value ? old_val += new_val : old_val
    end
  end
end
```

Let me know how you get on with these!

Comment: Did this help at all @Mongoid?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
arr.group_by { |item| item[:partner_id] }.transform_values do |items| 
  items_values_sum = items.sum { |item| item[:value] }
  items.first.merge(value: items_values_sum) 
end.values
```

`transform_values` is cool but we have from ruby 2.4.0, otherwise use `map` as @SRack pointed out

Comment: Nice. Didn't know of `transform_values`. +1

Comment: New stuff bro :D

Answer (score 0):

This is short and emphasizes the Map / Reduce nature of the problem nicely:

```
arr.group_by{|e| e[:partner_id]}.map do |_,v|
  v.reduce{|r,e| r.merge! value: r[:value].to_i + e[:value] }
end
```

Comment: Considering that the asker is probably pretty new to Ruby, do you think you've provided adequate explanation for your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Your question concerns a very common operation in Ruby apps. There are always two general approaches that can be taken to this kind of problem. The first is to employ the method [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by).

**Use `group_by`**

```
hash = res.group_by { |h| h[:partner_id] }
  #=> {787=>[{:partner_name=>"company 1", :partner_id=>787, :value=>1},
  #          {:partner_name=>"company 1", :partner_id=>787, :value=>2}],
  #    768=>[{:partner_name=>"company 2", :partner_id=>768, :value=>1}],
  #    769=>[{:partner_name=>"company 3", :partner_id=>769, :value=>1}]}
```

We now wish to construct an array of three elements, each element corresponding to a key-value pairs of `hash`. The first element of that array, constructed from

```
hash[787]
  #=> [{:partner_name=>"company 1", :partner_id=>787, :value=>1},
  #    {:partner_name=>"company 1", :partner_id=>787, :value=>2}]
```

is

```
{:partner_name=>"company 1", :partner_id=>787, :value=>3}
```

As we are converting each key-value pair of `hash` to something else (a hash), the method [Enumerable#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) should come to mind. Here's one way to do that conversion.

```
hash.map do |k,v|
  # obtain the sum of the values of :value over each element (hash) of v
  tot = v.sum { |h| h[:value] }
  # merge { :value=>tot } into any element of `v` (say, v.first)
  v.first.merge(:value=>tot)
end
  #=> [{:partner_name=>"company 1", :partner_id=>787, :value=>3},
  #    {:partner_name=>"company 2", :partner_id=>768, :value=>1},
  #    {:partner_name=>"company 3", :partner_id=>769, :value=>1}]
```

`v.first.merge(:value=>tot)` is a commonly-used shortcut for `v.first.merge( {:value=>tot} )`.

The other answers show ways to do this with fewer statements, but the basic idea is the same. Incidentally, [Enumerable#sum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum) made its debut in Ruby v2.4. To support older versions, use [Enumerable#reduce](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (aka `inject`).

```
tot = v.reduce(0) { |t,h| t + h[:value] }
```

**Use the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that employs a block to determine the values of keys present in both hashes being merged.**

With this approach we will construct a hash `hash` whose keys are the distinct values of `:partners_id`, but, unlike `group_by`, whose values are the desired hashes that reflect the totals of the key `:value` for the given key of `hash`. Once that has been done we simply return the values of the hash `hash`.

```
hash = res.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  h.update(g[:partner_id]=>g) {|k,o,n| o.merge(:value=>o[:value]+n[:value])}        
end
  #=> {787=>{:partner_name=>"company 1", :partner_id=>787, :value=>3},
  #    768=>{:partner_name=>"company 2", :partner_id=>768, :value=>1},
  #    769=>{:partner_name=>"company 3", :partner_id=>769, :value=>1}}
```

The array `hash`'s values therefore provides the desired return value.

```
hash.values
  #=> [{:partner_name=>"company 1", :partner_id=>787, :value=>3},
  #    {:partner_name=>"company 2", :partner_id=>768, :value=>1},
  #    {:partner_name=>"company 3", :partner_id=>769, :value=>1}]
```

Let's look at how `hash` was constructed.

We first compute an enumerator.

```
enum = res.each_with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator: [
  #     {:partner_name=>"company 1", :partner_id=>787, :value=>1},
  #     {:partner_name=>"company 2", :partner_id=>768, :value=>1},
  #     {:partner_name=>"company 3", :partner_id=>769, :value=>1},
  #     {:partner_name=>"company 1", :partner_id=>787, :value=>2}
  #   ]:each_with_object({})>
```

Notice that

```
hash == enum.each do |g,h|
  h.update(g[:partner_id]=>g) {|k,o,n| o.merge(:value=>o[:value]+n[:value])}
end
  #=> true
```

[Enumerator#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-each) causes The first value of the enumerator is be generated and passed to the block, and values are assigned to the block variables using *disambiguation* (sometime called *deconstruction*).

```
g,h = enum.next
  #=> [{:partner_name=>"company 1", :partner_id=>787, :value=>1}, {}]
g #=> {:partner_name=>"company 1", :partner_id=>787, :value=>1}
h #=> {}
```

See [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-next). We may now perform the block calculation.

```
h.update(g[:partner_id]=>g) {|k,o,n| o.merge(:value=>o[:value]+n[:value])}
  #=> h.update(787=>{:partner_name=>"company 1", :partner_id=>787, :value=>1})
  #=> {787=>{:partner_name=>"company 1", :partner_id=>787, :value=>1}}
```

Because `h` is empty (no keys), merging the hash `{ 787=>{:partner_name=>"company 1", :partner_id=>787, :value=>1} }` into it does require `update`'s block to be consulted, as there are no keys present in both hashes being `merged!`. The same is true after each of the next two values of `enum` are passed to the block.

```
g,h = enum.next
  #=> [{:partner_name=>"company 2", :partner_id=>768, :value=>1},
  #    {787=>{:partner_name=>"company 1", :partner_id=>787, :value=>1}}]
g #=> {:partner_name=>"company 2", :partner_id=>768, :value=>1}
h #=> {787=>{:partner_name=>"company 1", :partner_id=>787, :value=>1}}
h.update(g[:partner_id]=>g)
  #=> {787=>{:partner_name=>"company 1", :partner_id=>787, :value=>1},
  #    768=>{:partner_name=>"company 2", :partner_id=>768, :value=>1}}

g,h = enum.next
  #=> [{:partner_name=>"company 3", :partner_id=>769, :value=>1},
  #    {787=>{:partner_name=>"company 1", :partner_id=>787, :value=>1},
  #     768=>{:partner_name=>"company 2", :partner_id=>768, :value=>1}}]
g #=> {:partner_name=>"company 3", :partner_id=>769, :value=>1}
h #=> {787=>{:partner_name=>"company 1", :partner_id=>787, :value=>1},
  #    768=>{:partner_name=>"company 2", :partner_id=>768, :value=>1}}
h.update(g[:partner_id]=>g)
  #=> {787=>{:partner_name=>"company 1", :partner_id=>787, :value=>1},
  #    768=>{:partner_name=>"company 2", :partner_id=>768, :value=>1},
  #    769=>{:partner_name=>"company 3", :partner_id=>769, :value=>1}}
```

Notice how `h` is updated at each step. Things change when the final element of `enum` is generated and passed to the block.

```
g,h = enum.next
  #=> [{:partner_name=>"company 1", :partner_id=>787, :value=>2},
  #    {787=>{:partner_name=>"company 1", :partner_id=>787, :value=>1},
  #     768=>{:partner_name=>"company 2", :partner_id=>768, :value=>1},
  #     769=>{:partner_name=>"company 3", :partner_id=>769, :value=>1}}]
g #=> {:partner_name=>"company 1", :partner_id=>787, :value=>2}
h #=> {787=>{:partner_name=>"company 1", :partner_id=>787, :value=>1},
  #    768=>{:partner_name=>"company 2", :partner_id=>768, :value=>1},
  #    769=>{:partner_name=>"company 3", :partner_id=>769, :value=>1}}
h.update(g[:partner_id]=>g) {|k,o,n| o.merge(:value=>o[:value]+n[:value])}
  #=> {787=>{:partner_name=>"company 1", :partner_id=>787, :value=>3},
  #    768=>{:partner_name=>"company 2", :partner_id=>768, :value=>1},
  #    769=>{:partner_name=>"company 3", :partner_id=>769, :value=>1}}
```

When `{ g[:partner_id]=>g} #=> { 787=>g }`is merged into `h` we see that both hashes have the common key `787`. We therefore defer to the block to determine the value of `787` in the merged hash. The values of the three block variables are as follows.

```
k = 787    # the common key
o = h[787] # the "old" value of k 
n = g      # the "new" value of k
```

Note

```
o[:value] #=> 1
n[:value] #=> 2
```

The block calculation is therefore

```
o.merge(:value=>o[:value]+n[:value])
  #=> h[787].merge( { :value=>1+2 }
  #=> {:partner_name=>"company 1", :partner_id=>787, :valu}
```

`The current value of`h`is returned, concluding the construction of`hash`.